# How to automatically transfer files from USB OTG to internal storage or internal storage to USB OTG, when USB OTG connected in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, usb, file-transfer

I have developed an application which detects OTG USB using felhr85:UsbSerial library in Android. Now, I need to transfer specific files from Usb to phone and from phone to usb(automatically, when USB connected,detected). How can I do this, I haven't any idea. Please answer me with code.